# Change drop folder of Visual Studio Team Services / Visual Studio Online Build to Assembly Version

Tags: build, msbuild, azure-devops

I want my Visual Studio Team Services Build to use the Assembly Version of my Executable. Is there any simple way to achieve that?

I know it is possible to pass parameters into the build process, but how can i define a parameter in one step and consume it later ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you question correctly. You can pass variables from a build task back to VSTS by calling the [task.servariable Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md):

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue
```

So you could write a PowerShell script to get the assembly version and pass this back to VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

First, set your build number format to what you want. I use: ***$(BuildDefinitionName)_1.0.0$(Rev:.r)***.
Then, call this in a PowerShell Script build step before you build the solution:

```
Param(
  [string]$pathToSearch = $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY,
  [string]$buildNumber = $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER,
  [string]$searchFilter = "AssemblyInfo.*",
  [regex]$pattern = "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+",
  [regex]$pattern2 = "AssemblyProduct(\()("".*?"")",
  [regex]$pattern3 = "AssemblyCopyright(\()("".*?"")",
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$assemblyProduct,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$Copyright
)
# Pattern: "AssemblyProduct(\()("".*?"")"
# Replace: "AssemblyProduct(""$assemblyProduct"""

try
{
    if ($buildNumber -match $pattern -ne $true) {
        Write-Host "Could not extract a version from [$buildNumber] using pattern [$pattern]"
        exit 1
    } else {
        $extractedBuildNumber = $Matches[0]
        Write-Host "Using version $extractedBuildNumber"

        gci -Path $pathToSearch -Filter $searchFilter -Recurse | %{
            Write-Host "  -> Changing $($_.FullName)"

            # remove the read-only bit on the file
            sp $_.FullName IsReadOnly $false

            # Get the copyright string from a local file
            #$Copyright = Get-Content TeamBuildScripts\PSScripts\Copyright.txt


            # run the regex replace
            (gc $_.FullName) | % { $_ -replace $pattern, $extractedBuildNumber } | sc $_.FullName
            (gc $_.FullName) | % { $_ -replace $pattern2, "AssemblyProduct(""$assemblyProduct""" } | sc $_.FullName
            (gc $_.FullName) | % { $_ -replace $pattern3, "AssemblyCopyright(""$Copyright""" } | sc $_.FullName
        }

        Write-Host "Done!"
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host $_
    exit 1
}
```